# Why did Dorian Gray react like this to his portrait?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen

In "[The Picture of Dorian Gray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Picture_of_Dorian_Gray)" by Oscar Wilde, Dorian could look upon his portrait as much as he liked until it eventually drove him mad and he killed the painter; Basil Hallward

He didn't die or age until he stabbed the painting but I'm wondering why the change in the story for the film [League of Extraordinary Gentlemen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0311429/)?

Comment: because they felt like it? note the variations in all the other characters' stories

Comment: This is a good question. Dorian Gray is not in the comic book and, even for a pastiche like LXG, his reaction to the portrait is entirely at odds with _The Picture of Dorian Gray_; in it, Dorian frequently looks at the portrait to see how his sins get reflected in it.

Comment: @AndresF. - He's pictured on the cover of the comic. His portrait hangs in the "secret annex" where the LXG is headquartered; http://www.expertcomics.com/enr//wp-content/uploads/2012/03/LEAGUEOFEXTRA.jpg

Comment: *I'm wondering why the change in the story for the film League of Extraordinary Gentlemen.* Any chance you could explain what the change actually is, for people like me who've read the book but not seen the film? :)

Comment: Within the film, viewing his portrait was enough to kill him versus the book where he actually had to stab it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Within the film, viewing his portrait was enough to kill him versus
>   the book where he actually had to stab it.

When Dorian stabs the painting in the book, he's attempting to destroy what the portrait represents - the evidence of his corruption - and therefore his conscience. Wilde is saying that to live without conscience is death.

In the film, Dorian is killed by a supernatural power innate in the portrait. Unsatisfying, with hints of deus ex machina, but perhaps more suitable for an action film.

Comment: Thank you, also nice work with latin. Ego etiam latinam loquis

Comment: I can't honestly claim any skill with Latin; it's one phrase every screenwriter knows: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I think that it was supposed to be a sort of parallelism to Mina's vampirism. Much as she could (presumably) be destroyed by the presentation of a holy symbol or sustained sunlight, he was destroyed by a revelation of his self. You can also see parallels between a vampire's inability to cast a reflection (a lack of a soul. In some forms of folklore, it also transfixes the vampire as he's forced to keep searching for his reflection, leading to destruction when the sun comes up) and Dorian's inability to look upon the painting, which contains a reflection of his twisted soul.

They may have also made the change to avoid some sort of fridge logic about why Dorian didn't fall down dead in the middle of that concerted gun battle from ricocheted bullets going through the portrait wherever he was keeping it.

Comment: Its a well thought out answer but you started with personally. Its a good opinion but i would like an actual answer

Comment: Fair enough. Although, unless one of the commentary tracks mentions it or someone finds a citation from one of the writers, we're probably going to be stuck with personal opinions.

Comment: I understand and will give you the 50 anyway if i dont get a better answer

Comment: 19hrs and counting and youll be 50pt richer

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have your rented the movie and checked out the commentary track to see if they said anything?